# Mongodb complex script involving multiple collections

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, for-loop, nosql-aggregation

I'm new to mongodb and I was asked to complete a task:

Some information:

The mongodb version that is being used is 3.4.9. The script needs to be done using mongo shell.

I have two collections - 'A' and 'B'

I want to update a field in the 'A' collection if the value of a document of an array matches a field of 'B'....How can I do this?

Example:

Document in Collection 'A':

    `_id: 1,
    name: john,
    alias:[ {name: doe},
          {name: holmes}
    ],
    status: dead`

Document in Collection 'B':

`_id: 1,
    alias: doe,
    address: london`

Basically, I need the script to loop through all the values in the 'alias.name' field of collection 'A' and reference them to the value of 'alias' in collection 'B'. If there is a match, I want to update the 'status' field in collection 'A' to 'active'. Otherwise, it should do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should do what you need

```
var docs = db.A.find({}, { alias: 1, status: 1 });

while (docs.hasNext()) {
  var currentDoc = docs.next();
  if (currentDoc.alias && currentDoc.alias.length) {
    var aliasList = currentDoc.alias.map(function(alias){
        return alias.name;
    })
    var existInB = db.B.findOne({ alias: { $in: aliasList } });
    if (existInB && existInB._id) {
      db.A.updateOne({ _id: currentDoc._id }, { $set: { status: 'active' }});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One more question: 
What would I do in a situation where the field names "alias" and "name"  in collection'B' are switched?

Comment: I don't get your question? And please mark the answer as correct if it answers you original question.

Comment: lets say that in the alias of the collection A,  alias:[ {name: doe} ], exists and in collection B:[ alias: doe ]  field does not exist. How can I check that and update collection A based on this?

Comment: in this case I would suggest using aggregation on collection A `$unwind`  alias then `$lookup` on collection B. This way you will get each alias in a separate document and any matching documents from B. if no matching documents found then you can update document in collection A.